# command 'sfdx.force.project.create' not found?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, visualstudiocode

I have installed Visual Studio code and Salesforce CLI(I confirmed in CMD by typing sfdx) but when I start new project in it says"command 'sfdx.force.project.create' not found".

Comment: Can you specify your operating system , cli version and vscode version and Salesforce vscode extension version

Comment: It looks like, you have a period after sfdx. It should be a space.

Comment: When you say, "start a project", do you mean typing it in the command line? Or do you mean using the command palette? Have you tried both?

Answer (score 1):

Its not dot `.`. It should be colon `:`.

> cd path/to/your/sfdx/projects
>   sfdx force:project:create --projectname MyLWC
>   cd MyLWC

Comment: sfdx.force.project.create is vscode extension command .Looks like vscode extension is not getting activated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command palette (Ctrl+shift+P or command+shift+p) which often helps avoid typos from the command line. [image: Command Pallette]